# using DeleteLocalRef on references from jni's CallStaticObjectMethod

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I get that the NewStringUTF creates a local reference, but I can't seem to find a convincing source online that says otherwise about CallStaticObjectMethod etc. Do these need to be given the DeleteLocalRef treatment?

I mean, I saw that it's okay to just leave it until the native function returns to the java caller, but **is it wrong to call DeleteLocalRef on these CallStaticObjectMethod return values**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it creates a local reference.  If it didn't, how would the garbage collector know not to collect it while your JNI function is running?  However, unless you explicitly make an additional reference to it you don't need to delete it-  JNI will handle that.  Doing so for it is going to cause more problems than help.  The only time you should be calling the Delete function is if you previously had manually increased the reference count in order to store it for use in C outside of the function that created it.

Also, if you want to make your JNI memory management dead simple, just use PushLocalFrame and PopLocalFrame, and put all your code in between them.  It's the easiest way to be correct.

Comment: There are some scenarios where "PushLocalFrame and PopLocalFrame, and put all your code in between" won't be appropriate and others that take a bit of thought. One, in particular is very common: returning a Java object created as a local reference. In that case, you need to pass the object to `PopLocalFrame` to tell it re-reference it in the outer frame (in other words, not to free the object). This is mentioned in [JNI Local Reference Changes in ICS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html) but applies generally.